# Why this error in VB.Net code which works fine in C# (after syntax changes)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I come from a C# background and have to now code in VB.Net (new job)

I am writing a code in VB.Net which works fine in C# (after syntax changes) but in VB.Net it gives error of `Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers`.

**C# Code**

```
TimeSpan yesterday = new TimeSpan(1, 19, 0);

DateTime today = new DateTime(2012, 9, 4, 8, 48, 0);

DateTime ts = today.Add(new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)).Subtract(yesterday);
```

**VB.Net Code**

```
Dim yesterday As New TimeSpan(1, 19, 0)

Dim today As New DateTime(2012, 9, 4, 8, 48, 0)

Dim ts As today.Add(New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)).Subtract(yesterday)
```

It gives this error under `New` of 3rd line of VB code. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think, this question deserves so many downvotes.

Comment: I agree, it's not a stupid question just someone trying to understand VB from a c# developers perspective.

Comment: You may want to switch to using the Date keyword instead of DateTime. I personally don't like it, but I grudgingly do so because it's the VB way.

Comment: @SteveDog: But aren't they both alias of `System.DateTime`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Yes. It won't make a difference. I generally stick with `DateTime`.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Yeah Me too.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal yes, `Date` is just an alias for `System.DateTime`, so either will work perfectly fine and it's just a matter of preference.  However, it's typically advised that you use the aliases when they are available.  For instance, I'm sure in C# you used `int`, even though it was just an alias to `Int32`.  And I would expect, similarly, that you will be using the equivalent `Integer` alias when writing code in VB.NET. Like I said, I personally don't like it. I wish the aliases didn't exist at all or were discouraged, but as long as they are there and encouraged, I'd recommend complying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Dim ts As today.Add(New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)).Subtract(yesterday)
```

should be

```
Dim ts = today.Add(New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)).Subtract(yesterday)
```

or

```
Dim ts As DateTime = today.Add(New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)).Subtract(yesterday)
```

---

When declaring a variable, you use `As` as type specifier.

```
Dim x As Int32
x = 10
```

or

```
Dim x As Int32 = 10
```

When assigning a value to the variable on the same line, you can omit the type specifier.

```
Dim x = 10
```

---

Because of this, I generally don't mix up `As` and `New` like this

```
Dim x As New FooBar()
```

as I think it is somewhat confusing. I prefer

```
Dim x = New Foobar()
```

Comment: Unless something changed in a recent version of .NET, leaving out the "As" part is not really the same thing, and in fact, is not allowed if `Option Strict` is set to `On`.  If you leave out the "As", it will create it as an `Object` with no type checking.  That, of course, may be what you want sometimes, but usually it isn't.

Comment: @SteveDog No. You can just omit the `As` part and the compiler will infer the correct type.

Comment: @SteveDog You can of course disable `Option Infer`, then you would be right. But why would anybody want to do this? :-)

Comment: Do you know when that was changed by any chance?  I'm stuck in VS 2005 for some inexplicable reason at work, so I'm curious...

Comment: Yes yes yes, no need to rub it in :)

Comment: @SteveDog `Option Infer` was added in 2008, not 2010

Answer (score 1):

you must explicitly declare the data type especially for "known" data types. Remember that Visual Basic is `CASE INSENSITIVE`

```
Dim ts As datetime = today.Add(New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)).Subtract(yesterday)
```

but you can omit the datatype of the variable if have set

```
Option Infer ON
```

by default, it's `ON`

Comment: -1 You don't have to explicitly declare data types - that is what `Option Infer` is all about. `Dim ts = today.Add(New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)).Subtract(yesterday)` works perfectly well